# Can I call a checkbox by it's name with a variable component in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, string, object, checkbox

I want to loop through a Range with values and attach them to a string. The result is then the name of a checkbox of which I want to know whether it's true or False. I think it recognizes the name as a string. Is there a way around it?
I tried something like this:

```
MyValues = Range("A1:A12")

For each item in MyValues
if "Box" & item.Value = True then
MsgBox("Box is ticked")
elseif
MsgBox("Box not ticked")
end if
next
```

Comment: What type of checkbox?

Comment: Checkbox is on a worksheet?

Comment: No, it's in a userform

Comment: Might have been useful to mention that you're working with a userform...  Try `If Me.Controls("Box" & item).Value = True then`